# UltraEdit v. 12 will not open utf8 file as utf8

Tags: utf-8, ultraedit

Even if auto detection of utf8 files is ON and you instruct the editor to open the file as utf8 in the Open dialog, UtraEdit will open the file as ASCII.

Answer (score 1):

UltraEdit version 12 is an unprecise version information. There were several UTF-8 related fixes from UE v12.00 released on 2006-03-15 to version 12.20b+1 released on 2007-01-02 which was the last 12.xx version.

The UTF-8 detection algorithm is explained in UltraEdit forum topic [UTF-8 not recognized, largish file](https://www.ultraedit.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=7015). There are further [Using UTF-8 with UltraEdit](https://www.ultraedit.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=3511) and [UTF-8 auto-detection problem with first multi-byte after 10k](https://www.ultraedit.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=3690) and some other topics related to UTF-8 in UltraEdit forum which can be found using the [UltraEdit forum search](https://www.ultraedit.com/forums/search.php) searching for the words **UTF** and **open**.

But I don't really know what to answer as your question does not contain any question. All you wrote is that a file we can't see opens in UltraEdit v12.xx always as ASCII/ANSI file even with selecting UTF-8 in the *File Open* dialog. We can't verify your statement without having the file for verification and of course knowing the full version of the now already 8 year old UltraEdit version you still use for some unknown reason.

Comment: Hi @Mofi. Thanks for all the links, I really appreciate it. I just wanted to put the problem that I had here and also the simple solution that I've found to it. Hopefully people will find it while searching so they will not lose too much time with it. An up to date version of UltraEdit I'm sure would help.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the problem is that the algorithm that utf8 uses to detect utf8 files is only using the start of the file. So to make sure the file is detected as utf8 I just put an "utf8 trap" at the beginning of the file, in a comment:

```
<!-- €șăâțÎȚȘĂÂ - utf8 trap -->
```

Still not sure why UtraEdit does not listen to the Format field in the Open dialog...

Make sure you have the right configuration first http://www.ultraedit.com/support/tutorials_power_tips/ultraedit/unicode.html